# Xcode Building OpenGL Mistake link commande failure with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, opengl, clang

these days I am learning something about OpenGL in the website LearnOpenGL(https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle),and i use Xcode to run the code.My Xcode's version is 10.0 (10A255).About several days before, after the command line tool is updated, some code can not be compiled.The error information is linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).[I have add the link library already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZX3I.png)

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int 
height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main()
{

  glfwInit();
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  #ifdef __APPLE__
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
  #endif


  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
  if (window == NULL)
  {
      std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
      glfwTerminate();
      return -1;
   }
   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
   glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);


   if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
   {
      std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
      return -1;
   }



   int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
   glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
   glCompileShader(vertexShader);

   int success;
   char infoLog[512];
   glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
   if (!success)
   {
      glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
   }

   int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
   glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
   glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

   glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
   if (!success)
   {
      glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
   }

    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
      glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
     }
     glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
     glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top
};

unsigned int VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


glBindVertexArray(0);


while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{

    processInput(window);

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw our first triangle
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
  }

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
   if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
 }

 void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
 {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
 }
```

Comment: well, the problem is that the OpenGL version is 4.1 while the glad is for the OpenGL v3.3

Comment: How do you know those versions? Which function in your code requires OpenGL version beyond 3.3?

Comment: Well, i used the GLAD library, and generated it from the website, it should match the current version of the opengl version used in the Xcode

Comment: GLAD is a function-retriever, like GLEW. They don't set a OpenGL version. If you are coding for MacOS no function-retriever is needed.

Comment: You say your problem is with the linker, despite of you set the OpenGL.framework. Please, edit your question and copy&paste the full error message.